# Count number of distinct columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Value1,value2,value3) From table1
```

and get something like

```
        #   value1  value2  value3
--------------------------------------
        1.  result1 result1 result2
        2.  result1 result2 result2
        3.  result5 result6 result7
```

How would I add an extra column that tells me how many times that unique combination of values appears, such as (last column is how many times it occurs):

```
 #    value1  value2  value3      #occurred
--------------------------------------
 1.  result1 result1 result2      15
 2.  result1 result2 result2      25
 3.  result5 result6 result7      35
```

Comment: use `count(*)` grouping by those 3 columns.

Comment: Note that `distinct` is not a function. Instead, `distinct` alters the behavior of `select`. Think of it as `select distinct`, as opposed to `select all`, rather than choosing columns to select. You shouldn't put parens around it, that's some non-standard MySQL thing.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a keyword that applies to the entire list of expressions, it's not a function. The parens aren't necessary. Extraneous parens aren't invalid, but there's no reason to include them.  As `vkp` notes,  remove the `DISTINCT` keyword, add a `GROUP BY` clause, and add a `COUNT()` aggregate to the SELECT list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`group by`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) instead of `distinct`. Then you can use `count`.

```
select value1, value2, value3, count(*) as occurred
from table1
group by value1, value2, value3;
```

A demonstration in SQLite.

```
sqlite> select * from table1 order by value1, value2, value3;
value1      value2      value3    
----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           2         
1           1           2         
1           2           2         
1           2           2         
1           2           2         
5           6           7         

sqlite> select value1, value2, value3, count(*) as '#occurred' from table1 group by value1, value2, value3;
value1      value2      value3      #occurred 
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           2           2         
1           2           2           3         
5           6           7           1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT    Value1,value2,value3,count(*)
From      table1
group by  Value1,value2,value3
```